# Meaning of 一样 in 你要像喜欢甜一样喜欢苦

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, comparison

```
你要像喜欢甜一样喜欢苦
```

My questions are

(1) What does 一样 means in this sentence?

(2) Can I put VERBS following 一样? E.g: 我跟Mary一样喜欢那种菜。(Both I and Mary like that dish)

(3) If my example is wrong, how can it be corrected?

Comment: You have to like(喜欢) bitterness like(一样) sweetness

Comment: 1) "the same way". 2) "那道菜". What you wrote means "that type of vegetables"  3) Usage is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 你要像喜欢甜一样喜欢苦
>
> (1) What does 一样 means in this sentence?

"像 (X)一样" means "the same as (X) "  or "like (X)" in this sentence

- 你要喜欢苦 = You have to love bitter
- 你要[**像**喜欢甜**一样**]喜欢苦 = You have to love bitter [**the same as** you love sweet] /  You have to love bitter [**like** you love sweet]

[像喜欢甜一样] is an adverbial phrase that modify the verb phrase 喜欢苦

> 2) Can I put VERBS following 一样?

My answer to (1) said you can,  because [像 X 一样 ] = [the same as X], and the following sentence can be a verb phrase or adjectival phrase E.g.  "像 Mary 一样去當護士了" or "像 Mary 一样漂亮"

Comment: It means without 像， I cannot put verbs following 一样，right? And my example should be “像Mary一样，我喜欢那种菜。”？

Comment: You need "像"  in the  adverbial phrase "像 X 一样" --    "Mary 一样，我喜欢那种菜" in incorrect; but you can write "Mary 也欢那种菜"  (Mary too, love that kind of dish)

Comment: ”跟 Mary 一样，我也喜欢那种菜” is also a valid sentence.

Comment: So are 和 Mary 一样，與 Mary 一样，同 Mary 一样 (Cantonese).  [跟/和/與 (X) 一样] = [same as (X)]